# Generating polynom for stirling numbers of second kind - Where's my mistake?

Tags: proof-verification, generating-functions, stirling-numbers

Let $S(a,b)$ denote the Stirling numbers of the second kind, i.e. the number of partitions of a set with $a$ elements into $b$  non-empty subsets.

Let further denote 
$$
F_k\left(x\right)=\sum_{n\geq0}{S\left(k,n\right)x^n}
$$
the generating function for the Stirling numbers, where we set $k$ as a fixed parameter.

We immediately get that 
$$
F_k\left(x\right)=\sum_{n\geq0}{S\left(k,n\right)x^n}=\sum_{n\geq0}^{k}{S\left(k,n\right)x^n}
$$
, as we can't partition a set into more subsets than it has elements.

We start with $\sum_{n\geq0}{S\left(k,n\right)x^n}$ and substitute into it the recurrence $S(a,b) = S(a-1,b-1)+k\cdot S(a-1,b)$:

$$
\begin{align*}
&\sum_{n\geq0}{S\left(k,n\right)x^n}=\left(\sum_{n\geq0}{S\left(k-1,n-1\right)x^n}\right)+k\cdot\sum_{n\geq0}{S\left(k-1,n\right)x^n}\\&\Leftrightarrow\\&F_k\left(x\right)=\left(\sum_{n\geq0}{S\left(k-1,n-1\right)x^n}\right)+k\cdot F_{k-1}\left(x\right)\\&\Leftrightarrow\\&F_k\left(x\right)=\left(\sum_{n\geq1}{S\left(k-1,n-1\right)x^n}\right)+k\cdot F_{k-1}\left(x\right)\ +\ S\left(k-1,-1\right)x^0\\&\Leftrightarrow\\&F_k\left(x\right)=x\left(\sum_{n\geq0}{S\left(k-1,n\right)x^n}\right)+k\cdot F_{k-1}\left(x\right)\ \\&\Leftrightarrow\\&F_k\left(x\right)=xF_{k-1}\left(x\right)+k\cdot F_{k-1}\left(x\right)\\&\Leftrightarrow\\&F_k\left(x\right)=\left(x+k\right)\cdot F_{k-1}\left(x\right)
\end{align*}
$$

Using the initial value $F_0(x) = 1$ we obtain the generating function:

$$
F_k(x) =\sum_{n\geq0}{S\left(k,n\right)x^n}= \prod_{i=1}^{k}\left(x+i\right)
$$

So, if I e.g. set $k=5$ I should obtain:
$$
\prod_{i=1}^{5}\left(x+i\right)  = S(5,0) + S(5,1)x + ... + S(5,5)x^5
$$
However, this is wrong for $n=0$ already, as
$$
[x^0]\prod_{i=1}^{5}\left(x+i\right) = 5!
$$
and not $0$.

Where's my mistake?

---

After correcting (both the starting index as pointed out by John, as well as the mistake in the application of the recursion) it becomes:

$$
\begin{align*}
&\left(\sum_{n\geq1}{S\left(k,n\right)x^n}\right)+S\left(k,0\right)=\left(\sum_{n\geq1}{\left(S\left(k-1,n-1\right)+nS\left(k-1,n\right)\right)x^n}\right)+S\left(k,0\right)\\&\Leftrightarrow\\&\left(\sum_{n\geq0}{S\left(k,n\right)x^n}\right)=\left(\sum_{n\geq1}{S\left(k-1,n-1\right)x^n}\right)+\left(\sum_{n\geq1}{\left(nS\left(k-1,n\right)\right)x^n}\right)+S\left(k,0\right)\\&\Leftrightarrow\\&\left(\sum_{n\geq0}{S\left(k,n\right)x^n}\right)=x\left(\sum_{n\geq0}{S\left(k-1,n\right)x^n}\right)+\left(\sum_{n\geq1}{\left(nS\left(k-1,n\right)\right)x^n}\right)+S\left(k,0\right)\\&\Leftrightarrow\\&F_k\left(x\right)=xF_{k-1}\left(x\right)+\left(\sum_{n\geq0}{\left(nS\left(k-1,n\right)\right)x^n}\right)+S\left(k,0\right)\\&\Leftrightarrow\\&F_k\left(x\right)=xF_{k-1}\left(x\right)+x\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum_{n\geq0}{\left(S\left(k-1,n\right)\right)x^n}\right)+S\left(k,0\right)\\&\Leftrightarrow\\
&F_k\left(x\right)=xF_{k-1}\left(x\right)+x\frac{d}{dx}F_{k-1}\left(x\right)+S\left(k,0\right)
\end{align*}
$$

This now leads to a combination of a recursion with a ODE... which is frankly too much for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic mistake is you're using the recurrence relation outside of the range it's defined for. As the [Recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Recurrence_relation) section of Wikipedia's "Stirling numbers of the second kind" article states

> Stirling numbers of the second kind obey the recurrence relation
>      $\left\{{n+1 \atop k}\right\}=k\left\{{n \atop k}\right\}+\left\{{n \atop k-1}\right\}$
>   for $k \gt 0$ ...

Using your notation and equation, this becomes

> $$S(a,b) = S(a-1,b-1)+k\cdot S(a-1,b) \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

which is *only* applicable for $b \gt 0$. However, you're using it starting with $b = 0$ (i.e., $n = 0$) in your next steps.

I believe a roughly comparable situation is the recurrence relation for factorials. You have that $0! = 1$ and, for $n \gt 0$,

$$n! = n(n-1)! \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

If you try to go to before that, e.g., $0! = 0(-1)!$, you get that $(-1)! = \frac{1}{0}$, which can obviously cause issues if you're using it to try to prove something else. However, I'm not saying the same particular issue occurs here, but just that you can't necessarily trust the behavior of recurrence relations if you use them outside of their stated bounds.

Comment: Thank you! (And a nice example with the factorial!) I've changed my proof to account for the bounds of the recurision, however I still seem to have an error left in there. Just testing how the functions should look like for different $k$'s makes it seem that my proof is flawed to its very core

Comment: @Sudix You're welcome. I noticed the rest of the recurrence relation values and limits states the first variable must be $\gt 1$, but you're using at $k = 1$. I've updated my answer accordingly. I'm sorry for not noticing this earlier.

Comment: I've checked the proof for the recursion in my script, and there it says that $S(m,n) = S(m-1,n-1) + nS(m-1,n)$ is applicable for all $m,n\ge 1$. So, shouldn't that mean that I can safely use the recursion even for $k=1$?

Comment: I've just realized, that I got in the first line the very recursion itself wrong...

Comment: @Sudix I just realized the part where the article says $n \gt 0$ is *only* for the "$\left\{{n \atop 0}\right\}=\left\{{0 \atop n}\right\}=0$" part, as it initially gives that $\left\{{0 \atop 0}\right\}=1$. I'm sorry about that. Note I've rolled back my changes to before that update. Also, this is also likely why the proof for the recursion in your script indicates you can use it with $k=1$.

Comment: @Sudix Since you say you got the first line the very recursion itself wrong, I'll wait until you resolve it.

Comment: I'd guess that now the "proof", or what's left of it, is correct... at the same time, the result is a weird hybrid I have no hope of resolving, so I guess this is the finish line for me. Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: @Sudix You're welcome for my time & help. I didn't notice your other mistake either until I see it now with your updated answer. As for your result with a recursion involving an ODE, this could explain why your result is not more widely known & used.